# AWS ECS EC2 Capacity Provider not listed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a new `Capacity Provider`

I deployed the following CloudFormation snippet:

```
  myECSCapacityProvider:
      Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
      Properties:
        Name: my-project-asg-cp
        AutoScalingGroupProvider:
            AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref myAutoScalingGroup
            ManagedScaling:
                MaximumScalingStepSize: 10
                MinimumScalingStepSize: 1
                Status: ENABLED
                TargetCapacity: 100
            ManagedTerminationProtection: DISABLED
```

I have the resource ASG (myAutoScalingGroup) created.

When I go to the ECS console and then to the `Capacity Providers` tab it is blank, no CPs are listed.

If I try to create the same CP through the console, using the name `my-project-asg-cp` I see the following error:

```
There was an error creating the capacity provider. 

Fix the following error and try again.

The specified Auto Scaling group ARN is already being used by another capacity provider. 

Specify a unique Auto Scaling group ARN and try again.
```

So it seems somehow the CP was created but it is not listed.

And of course, I don't have any error in CloudFormation.
If I check the resources tab I can see the resource created:

```
myECSCapacityProvider  my-project-asg-cp  AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider  CREATE_COMPLETE
```

Also, the `cli` doesn't show it either.

Does anyone has faced this error?

Comment: did you checked this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-capacity-provider-create-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate the capacity provided with the cluster:

```
ECSCluster:
  Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
  Properties:
    ClusterName: <your-ecs-cluster>
    CapacityProviders:
      - !Ref myECSCapacityProvider
```